# Python code would run on boot but does not create a CSV file on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi, gpio, autostart

I have a python code that reads the data from a sensor and it creates a CSV file to write the data to that CSV file. In the code, I also added GPIO to show the code running by blinking an LED and having a push button to shutdown the Raspberry Pi. My goal is to have this code run when the Raspberry Pi boots when I power it on, have it to create a CSV file, and shut it down when I push the button.

The code works as intended when I run it on a terminal, meaning I am able to run the code, have it create a CSV file, and then shut it down by using the push button. The problem I am running into is that the code would start on boot but it doesn't create the CSV file. I know the code is running because the LED would be blinking. It also doesn't allow me to shut it down when using the push button.

Is this because I don't have the correct permission when the code runs on boot?

My method of starting the program on boot is by creating a .desktop file on path /home/pi/.config/autostart. In the .desktop file, I have:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Start_Collect_Temp
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Work/Temp_Folder/Collect_Temp.py
```

The way I am creating the CSV file is by using the os library.

```
import os

...

def init_csv():

    ... 

    try:
        csv_file = open(os.path.join("logs", filename), "w")
        csv_file.write("Date, Time, Current_Temp\n")
    except:
        print("Error creating file: {}".format(filename))
    else:
        print("File {} created...".format(filename))

    return csv_file

...

inf = init_csv()

...

row = "{}, {}, {}\n".format(date, time, curr_temp)
inf.write(row)

...
```

Comment: Hey @Hello_Aiden and welcome! If you're sure your code is running but the CSV file is not being created, I suspect the problem is not the method of starting the program but in your code itself. You might want to add some detail about that to your question

Comment: Where are you actually *looking* for the output file?  You aren't specifying a full pathname for it, so I'm not sure where it will end up - perhaps in `/root/logs/`...

Comment: @Benp44 Thanks for commenting. There seem to be nothing wrong with the code because it works as intended when I run the code in a terminal. The code is able to create a CSV file. It's only when I run the code at boot that it doesn't create a CSV file.

Comment: @jasonharper I am looking for the created CSV file on the same path as my code. In this case `/home/pi/Work/Temp_Folder/logs`

Comment: Why would it be *there*?  It will go somewhere relative to the current working directory of whatever system process runs autostart programs, which will certainly not be anywhere near your home directory.

Comment: @jasonharper I'm assuming it would be there because every time I run the code in the terminal that is where the created CSV file would be. My working directory is `/home/pi/Work/Temp_Folder`.

Comment: The working directory when *you* run it is utterly unrelated to the working directory when the system runs it

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the platform! It looks like that you need to run this command at the very beginning of your raspberry. For doing this I would recommend that you place your command inside `/etc/rc.local`.

For instance, it will be just a matter of placing your command in there, but beware that you script will block the rc.local. In order to avoid this, you can detach the process by appending an ampersand at the end of your command.

The file contents would look like this:

/etc/rc.local

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Collect_Temp.py &
```

If your command creates some sort of output, I recommend that you print the output on a place that you can catch later.

/etc/rc.local

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Collect_Temp.py > /home/pi/Desktop/CollectTempResults.txt 2>&1 &
```

For reference, please look at [rc.local - Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md).

I hope being helpful. Thank you and be safe! :)